# How do you remove a layout.js file in a Next JS project sub route without breaking app

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, layout, children

I am working on a nextjs 13.4 app using the app router, i pretty much love how straight forward it is. I get that you don't need to have a layout in all your sub routes, but as a test i created one in a route, turns out it's not needed so i tried deleting it but now the app requires it to compile.

How do you go about removing a layout.js file from a subroute without breaking the app ? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `.next` folder and restarting the app.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information. I do not understand what this folder is for and so understand why we should remove it and then how to regenerate it would be great info.
This answer has not been upvoted and I would say the lack of info is the reason.

Comment: When you start or build your nextjs app by running `npm start` or `npm run build`, nextjs creates a folder `.next` and stores the artefacts for your website here. usually, every time you restart your app or run another build the folder will be regenerated. But sometimes the folder can be stale, maybe because a file exists in the build that doesn't exist anymore. So you can delete the folder, but when you run start again. It will be regenerated hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this comment was way more helpful. Answers in SE SO need to be tailored to stupid people like me to understand.
more detail that is clear and concise and answers the exact question. Cheers